# Conditionally average values ​and display them in different columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table, 'people.sql' in SQL Server 2017. The table stores the name, age, nationality and status (Available/Busy) of people, like this.

```
CREATE TABLE people 
(
     name VARCHAR (50), 
     age INT, 
     nationality VARCHAR (50), 
     status VARCHAR (50)
);

INSERT INTO people VALUES ('Mabel', 50, 'England', 'Available');
INSERT INTO people VALUES ('Diana', 55, 'England', 'Busy');
INSERT INTO people VALUES ('Joanne', 42, 'Australia', 'Busy');
INSERT INTO people VALUES ('Carl', 35, 'Australia', 'Available');
INSERT INTO people VALUES ('Johan', 20, 'Australia', 'Available');
```

| name | age | nationality | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mabel | 50 | England | Available |
| Diana | 55 | England | Busy |
| Joanne | 42 | Australia | Busy |
| Carl | 35 | Australia | Available |
| Johan | 20 | Australia | Available |

Now, I need to generate a query to get the data as follows.

| nationality | busy_average_age | available_average_age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| England | 55 | 50 |
| Australia | 42 | 27.5 |

I tried to do the query but only managed to do it separately:

```
SELECT nationality, AVG(age) AS busy_average_age
FROM people 
WHERE status = 'Busy' 
GROUP BY nationality;
```

I would appreciate very much if you help me to do everything in a single query.

Comment: Your `INSERT INTO` statements all lack a `VALUES` keyword - assuming this is just a typo ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation (`CASE WHEN` inside an aggregation function):

```
SELECT
  nationality,
  AVG(CASE WHEN status = 'Busy' THEN age END) AS busy_average_age,
  AVG(CASE WHEN status = 'Available' THEN age END) AS available_average_age
FROM people 
GROUP BY nationality
ORDER BY nationality;
```

Comment: @Tomurain . . . You might want to multiply age by `1.0` to avoid an integer average.